# How to best mine on a smartphone?

Tags: hashpower, mining-hardware, cpu-mining

As you perhaps already know, mining started at the beginning with processors then graphic card.

I want to try to mining on a smartphone. Which electronic component will be the best to calculate hash? Processor or graphic component?

The purpose is only for testing on testnet and get the best performance.

Keywords such as mining and smartphone don't bring me any relevant results via Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mining on a smartphone is unfavourable and might drain your battery very fast. For bitcoin-mainnet and bitcoin-testnet don't even try to mine on a smartphone (it won't be fun).

If you like to do this for testing or research purposes, you probably should use your smartphones GPU over [openCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) or [renderScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renderscript).
Also have a look at [bitcoin-cores mining code](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/miner.cpp) if you like to know more about how mining works (in detail).

Comment: Thanks you ! You give me a way to search much more accurately what I would like to try. 

Like you said it's for research & test

Answer (score 1):

> according to you which electronic component will be the best to calcul
>   hash ? Processor or graphic componement ?

Both of them are absolutely useless for generating cryptos. Do not waste energy and time.

Comment: You are right, of course generating crypto even the new one with a smartphone is useless, it's more for research purposes but I forget to include that. Anyway thanks for your comment